# Android: How to get index id from databse from spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

guys is anyone know about getting index id value from spinner, i have this code, but it's error 
Akreditasi.java

```
public class Akreditasi {
private long id;
private String name;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return nama;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ID : " + id 
            + "\n" + "Nama :"+ name;
}

}
```

and here is mySpinner
i am trying passing this Akreditasi to ArrayAdapter

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) 
                    {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // On selecting a spinner item
            String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Akreditasi mSelected = (Akreditasi) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); //in here my program is crash, it's says cannot be cast 
                    long count = mSelected.getId();

            //set the default according to value
            // Showing selected spinner item
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You Selected: " + label,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and this is my spinner method

```
  private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // database handler
    DBDataSource db = new  DBDataSource(getApplicationContext());
    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabel_akreditasi();
    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



}
```

I still don't understand about this error, can anyone help me? Thank u

Comment: @Ranjith : it's say cannot be cast, the error is sign the code above

Comment: can i see the code where you set the Spinner

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your Akreditasi class? I guess constructor is needed to cast an object.

Comment: @Ranjith : i already just post it, can u see it?

Answer (score 1):

it because you didn't tell which spinner u'll use for this method,
first you need to call `onItemSelected`  method as below :

```
(your spinner).setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

after this, I suggest for adding `switch case` on your method `onItemSelected` as below :

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) 
                    {
switch (parent.getId()) {
case R.id.(id of your spinner):


  Akreditasi mSelected = (Akreditasi) parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
                    long count = mSelected.getId();
break;
}
}
```

your  spinner method should like this:

```
 private void loadSpinnerData() {
    DBDataSource db = new  DBDataSource(getApplicationContext());

    List<Akreditasi> lables = db.getAllLabel_akreditasi();

    ArrayAdapter<Akreditasi> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Akreditasi>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    dataAdapter .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: and what is arg0? @NenMa

Comment: okay, now it's working, but the the count cannot get the id, do u know  why this is happend? @NenMa

Comment: @ndr_sd see my edit, have you call `onItemSelected` method on your code?

Comment: I think, everything is working fine, my question now, where are you calling `Akreditasi`in `loadSpinnerData()` method?  ididn't see you call it

Answer (score 0):

while setting your setting your having only `List<String>` but not `List<Akreditasi>`

```
List<String> lables = db.getAllLabel_akreditasi();
```

you have to a logic to set Objects for Example code

```
    Akreditasi [] items = { 
                new Akreditasi (1, "Milk", 21.50), 
                new Akreditasi (2, "Butter", 15.99), 
                new Akreditasi (3, "Yogurt", 14.90), 
                new Akreditasi (4, "Toothpaste", 7.99), 
                new Akreditasi (5, "Ice Cream", 10.00), 
            };

            ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
// attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: if it helps let me know else send your db.getAllLabel_akreditasi(); also